# How to unhide inlay hints for a method in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, inlay-hints

I've previously selected the "Do not show hints for the current method" context action for a method to hide its parameter names, but now I'd like to undo that selection.

How do I make the hints again visible for that method?

The context actions don't show an option to show the hints for the current method after they have been hidden. I can't find in settings a list of methods for which hints have been disabled. I can't find a mention of that method in the configuration files inside the .idea directory.

Answer (score 0):

The list of methods whose parameter names have been hidden can be found in the settings at **Editor > Inlay Hints > Parameter names > JavaScript**. On this page there is a link to the **Exclude list**. (Note that it's on the "JavaScript" node of the tree, and not on any of the leaf nodes of the tree.)

[image: Exclude list location]